# How to unset option to Verbatim environment

Tags: fancyvrb, options

I am using the `fancyvrb` package to be able to have formatting (e.g., bold, color, etc.) in my verbatim environments.

This is easy enough to do by giving the `commandchars` option as seen in this MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\fvset{
  commandchars=\\\{\}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[frame=single]
  Here is some \textbf{bold} and {\color{red} red} text in a Verbatim environment.
\end{Verbatim}

\begin{Verbatim}
  Here is some text that breaks \
  because it is expecting a command
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

In *most* of my environments I want this formatting which is why I have

```
\fvset{
  commandchars=\\\{\},
}
```

However, there are a few of my Verbatim environments that I don't want `commandchars` set. (There is no formatting and the verbatim text contains `\`, which makes it look like the beginning of a command.)

**So how can I "unset" the `commandchars` option so that it returns to the default?** I've tried doing simply `commandchars=`, but then I get the error:

```
`commandchars' undefined
```

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Sorry, I thought it was enough. I guess I was wrong.

Comment: Does this help `\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=none] ...`?

Comment: @ArashEsbati Well, it did help for my MWE, but I couldn't get it to work with my non-MWE. Something else must be changing it elsewhere.

Comment: @ArashEsbati Okay, now that I've played with my full example, I've gotten your answer to work. If you make it into an answer, I'll accept it!

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Can't thank you enough! `[commandchars=none]` just works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fancyvrb` defines the `commandchars` key like this:

```
\define@key{FV}{commandchars}[\\\{\}]%
  {\def\@tempa{#1}%
    \ifx\@tempa\FV@None
      \let\FV@CommandChars\relax
    \else
      \FV@DefineCommandChars#1\relax\relax\relax
    \fi}
```

It checks if the value given is equal to `\FV@none`, which expands to `none`.  If true, it unsets the key, otherwise it defines it with the given value. Hence, you can unset this key for a single environment by doing something like this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\fvset{
  commandchars=\\\{\}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[frame=single]
  Here is some \textbf{bold} and {\color{red} red} text in a Verbatim environment.
\end{Verbatim}

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=none]
  Here is some text that breaks \
  because it is expecting a command
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```